Vignette study in Qualtrics using java script
I’m new to using java script in Qualtrics and I have a question - maybe someone here can help me?
I’m running a study where participants are randomly allocated to read one of 16 vignettes. Of course, I could set this up using the survey builder and survey flow, but I would like to use code - this is a pilot study for a larger experiment with over 500 vignettes, which would be too complicated to set up manually.
What I think I need to do is to set embedded data fields with variable names for each vignette, and then tell Qualtrics the corresponding vignette text for each name. Next, I can use the survey flow to randomly assign one vignette to each participant.
I have never used java script before, so this is the code I scrambled together (it’s probably totally wrong):
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  // Get the value of the selected variable from embedded data
  var selectedVariable = "${e://Field/SelectedVariable}";

  // Define the vignettes with their corresponding text
  var vignettes = {
    "aAA1BB1AB1BA1": "Text for vignette 1...",
    "aAA1BB1AB1BA0": "Text for vignette 2...",
    // Add more vignettes as needed
  };

  // Get the text for the selected vignette based on the selected variable
  var selectedVignetteText = vignettes[selectedVariable];

  // Set the text of the question to display the selected vignette
  this.getQuestionTextContainer().innerHTML = selectedVignetteText;
});

Could somebody help me with this?
I entered the code above in the java script window for a text/ graphic question, but when I click preview it just says "undefined".
I also tried to enter something similar into the html view in the rich text editor, but the code was never saved there and always disappeared.

Does "${e://Field/SelectedVariable}"; render as aAA1BB1AB1BA1? You could just do
const texts =  ["Text for vignette 1...", "Text for vignette 2..."], selectedVignetteText = vignettes[Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length)];

Thanks so much for the quick response!
Unfortunately, no on the first part...all I get is the line of code displayed in the question text. The same happens for the second suggestion.

Can you try this?
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  // Define the vignettes corresponding texts
  var texts = [
    "Text for vignette 1...",
    "Text for vignette 2...",
  ],selectedVignetteText = texts[Math.floor(Math.random() * texts.length)]
  console.log(selectedVignetteText)
  // Set the text of the question to display the selected vignette
  this.getQuestionTextContainer().innerHTML = selectedVignetteText;
});

